# Magento Not upload image in admin custom tab form

Tags: admin, tinymce

In Created Custom tab in magento. Image not upload in editor. That display error like **Uncaught ReferenceError: Mage is not defined**

in Edit.php file

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
 // added this code    
    if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) { 
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true); 
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true); 
    } 
}
```

in my Form

```
$configSettings = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(
                        array(
                        'add_widgets' => false,
                        'add_variables' => false,
                        'add_images' => true,
                        'files_browser_window_url'=>    $this->getBaseUrl().'admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/',
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the below code in **app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\[your_layout_file_name].xml**

```
     <default>
         <reference name="head">
             <action method="setCanLoadExtJs"><flag>1</flag></action>
             <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/variables.js</script></action>
             <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js</script></action>
             <action method="addJs"><script>lib/flex.js</script></action>
             <action method="addJs"><script>lib/FABridge.js</script></action>
             <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/flexuploader.js</script></action>
             <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/browser.js</script></action>
             <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/window.js</script></action>
             <action method="addJs"><script>events/adminhtml/product.js</script></action>
             <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>prototype/windows/themes/default.css</name></action>
         </reference>
     </default>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your Answers.
but i found my solution in my code.
just remove some code in my form

$configSettings = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig();

and add js files link in your module layout xml file.

```
<adminhtml_modulename_edit>
<reference name="head">
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js</name></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type>
</reference>
<update handle="editor"/>
</adminhtml_modulename_edit>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks `js/mage/cookies.js` is missing.  It defines the Mage Javascript class.

```
if (!window.Mage) var Mage = {};
```

add this in your xml file.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
```